# How to add item to list and delete item from list?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem with adding a new item via HTML form and PHP to a PHP file `data.json`,
after clicking `submit` on my button, my table is reloaded but my item is not saved into JSON file, can somebody tell me why?

PHP:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

function addToList() {
  $file = "data.json";
  $arr = array(
    'id' => count($data) + 1,
    'name' => $_GET['name'],
    'price' => $_GET['price'],
    'buyer' => $_GET['buyer']
  );
  $json_string = json_encode($arr);
  file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
}

if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
  addToList();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="get">
  <div id="form_page">
    <div id="form_body">
      <input id="name" type="text" Placeholder="Nazwa" name="name" required>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Cena" name="price" required>
      <input id="buyer" type="text" name="buyer" placeholder="Kupujący">
      <input type="submit" value="Wyślij">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" name="button1" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and I have another one question, how to delete (unset) items from JSON?

thanks for any help

Comment: The form doesn't know what to do with the values without an [`action` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_action_attribute). You'll need to set a path to the PHP script in that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Are your PHP and HTML code on the same file?

Your PHP code appears to be "correct enough" to write something to the `data.json` file. That seems to indicate that your PHP and HTML code are not on the same file. If that is the case, update your HTML `<form>` form and add an `action` property pointing to the PHP file/code.

Additionally, you have several issues in your PHP code though.

The `$data` variables outside and inside the `addToList()` function are two distinct variables.

If the `$data` is only referenced inside the function, then move the assignment inside the function, eg:

```
function addToList() {
    $file = "data.json";
    $jsonData = file_get_contents($file);
    $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    ...
}
```

If the `$data` is accessed outside the function as well, then pass it as a parameter, eg:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

...

function addToList(array $data) {
    ...
}

...

if (array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
  addToList($data);
}
```

If your function is a closure, you can give the closure access to the `$data` via `use`, eg:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

...

$addToList = function () use ($data) {
    ...
}

...

if (array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
  $addToList($data);
}
```

Another issue is that it seems you intend to append the new data to the `data.json` (`id` is based on the number of elements, plus one), but your code replaces the content of the JSON file with just the new data. Perhaps you meant:

```
...

function addToList(array $data) {
  $data[] = [
    'id' => count($data) + 1,
    'name' => $_GET['name'],
    'price' => $_GET['price'],
    'buyer' => $_GET['buyer']
  ];

  file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($data));
}

...
```